# I want to add 2nd and 3rd column if 1st column within range of 1 to 10000

Tags: perl

This is sample file with tab separted.

```
2000    46  26

3000    52  25

5149    4   3

10000   104 32

10500   20  12

13397   0   3

20000   20  12   

24489   8   0
```

I try this with my Perl code, this works fine with one condition then I unable to do the same in when the condition is increased to 10001 to 20000 and 30001 to 40000 and so on, until the end of the file.

I want output as :-

```
1 10000  102   54  

10001   20000  124  47 

20001   30000   28   12      so on.....  




#! /usr/bin/perl

my $file = "$ARGV[0]";
open (f, $file);
@f = <f>;

foreach $F1 (@f) {

    ($a, $b, $c) = split(/\t/, $F1);

    $x = "1";
    $y =  "10000" ;

    if ( ( $a > $x ) && ( $a <= $y ) ) {
        $total += $b ;
          $total_1 += $c;
    }

    #$x = $y;
    #$y = $y*2;
}

print "$x\t$y\t$total\t$total_1\n" ;
```

Comment: The code you show appears to work. Please show the program that isn't working.

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43153449/edit) to add the output that you are expecting. It's currently unclear what you mean by "I unable to do the same in when the condition is increased to 10001 to 20000 and 30001 to 40000 and so on".

Comment: @DaveCross I edit my question. Sorry for late response.

Comment: @Borodin Yes, this code is working but it does not work in a loop...I have large data so I want to add all in 10000 windows.sorry for late response

Comment: I am very new to this forum. Sorry for inconvenient. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By starting with the simple case and then trying to build on that, you're actually making things harder than they need to be. This is one example where seeing the bigger picture helps to simplify the code.

You're splitting your data into "buckets" - using the first column to determine which bucket the record should go into and then summing the second and third columns within a bucket.

I would write it something like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

# Store bucket totals here
my @totals;

# Read from STDIN
while (<>) {
  # Skip blank lines
  next unless /\S/;

  # Split the data on white space
  my @cols = split;

  # Calculate the bucket.
  #      1 - 10,000 is bucket 0
  # 10,001 - 20,000 is bucket 1
  # etc...
  my $bucket = int($cols[0] / 10_000);

  # Each element in @totals is a two-element array.
  # The first element is the sum of column two.
  # The second element is the sum of column three
  $totals[$bucket][0] += $cols[1];
  $totals[$bucket][1] += $cols[2];
}

# Walk the @totals array and display the results.
for (0 .. $#totals) {
  my $start = ($_ * 10_000) + 1;
  my $end   = ($_ + 1) * 10_000;
  say "$start $end $totals[$_][0] $totals[$_][1]";
}
```

As we read from `<>`, there is no need to bother with opening filehandles.

I put this in a file called `sum` and called it like this:

```
$ ./sum in.txt
```

And the result I got was:

```
1 10000 102 54
10001 10001 124 47
20001 10002 28 12
```

Which looks correct to me. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Yes, It works fine. Thanks a lot.It is very helpful for me because before it, I did it wth the awk command.